# How to interpose RabbitMQ between REST client and (Python) REST server?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

If I develop a REST service hosted in Apache and a Python plugin which services GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH; and this service is consumed by an Angular client (or other REST interacting browser technology).  Then how do I make it scale-able with RabbitMQ (AMQP)?

Potential Solution #1

- Multiple Apache's still faces off against the browser's HTTP calls.
- Each Apache instance uses an AMQP plugin and then posts message to a queue
- Python microservices monitor a queue and pull a message, service it and return response
- Response passed back to Apache plugin, in turn Apache generates the HTTP response

Does this mean the Python microservice no longer has any HTTP server code at all.  This will change that component a lot.  Perhaps best to decide upfront if you want to use this pattern as it seems it would be a task to rip out any HTTP server code.

Other potential solutions?  I am genuinely puzzled as to how we're supposed to take a classic REST server component and upgrade it to be scale-able with RabbitMQ/AMQP with minimal disruption.

Comment: if you are going to block the response until it finishes you might as well not use a q

Comment: This seems...weird. Do you actually have a specific performance issue that you're trying solve? Also, if scalability is a concern, why are you using *apache*?

Comment: @JaredSmith : no, this is just theoretical.   perhaps I have misunderstood the point of this technology.

Comment: @SMeaden yeah, it would make more sense to put RabbitMQ between your webserver and your other backend services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend switching wsgi to asgi(nginx can help here), Im not sure why you think rabbitmq is the solution to your problem, as nothing you described seems like that would be solved by using this method.

asgi is not supported by apache as far as I know, but it allows the server to go do work, and while its working it can continue to service new requests that come in. (gross over simplification)

If for whatever reason you really want to use job workers (rabbitmq, etc) then I would suggest returning to the user a "token" (really just the job_id) and then they can call with that token, and it will report back either the current job status or the result

Comment: Ok thanks, `ASGI is a spiritual successor to WSGI, the long-standing Python standard for compatibility between web servers, frameworks, and applications. WSGI succeeded in allowing much more freedom and innovation in the Python web space, and ASGI's goal is to continue this onward into the land of asynchronous Python.`  https://readthedocs.org/projects/asgi/downloads/pdf/latest/